# How to bind gridview using ajax?

Tags: asp.net

I have ASPX application. I can't bind gridview using Ajax. Ajax returns header row of gridview as datarow.

My Ajax code:

```
function bankmodulhargetir() {

// Bank modul values

var bankmodulvalues = {};

bankmodulvalues.bankmodulnom = $("#bankmodulnom").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodultarix = $("#bankmodultarix").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulverenbankkod = $("#bankmodulverenbankkod").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulherekettip = $('#bankmodulherekettip input[type=radio]:checked').val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulesastip = $("#bankmodulesastip").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulsirket = $("#bankmodulsirket").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulstatus = $("#bankmodulstatus").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulqeyd = $("#bankmodulqeyd").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulcemvalyuta = $("#bankmodulcemvalyuta").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulcemvalmebleg = $("#bankmodulcemvalmebleg").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulcemmebleg = $("#bankmodulcemmebleg").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodullayihe = $("#bankmodullayihe").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulherekettip2 = $("#bankmodulherekettip2").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulmusterikod = $("#bankmodulmusterikod").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulesaskod = $("#bankmodulesaskod").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulesaskod2 = $("#bankmodulesaskod2").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulvalyuta = $("#bankmodulvalyuta").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulkurs = $("#bankmodulkurs").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulvalmebleg = $("#bankmodulvalmebleg").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodulmebleg = $("#bankmodulmebleg").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodultertibeden = $("#bankmodultertibeden").val();
bankmodulvalues.bankmodultertibtarixi = $("#bankmodultertibtarixi").val();

var bankmoduljsonData = JSON.stringify({
    bankmodulvalues: bankmodulvalues
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Main.aspx/bankmodulhargetirstatic",
    data: bankmoduljsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});


function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var customers = xml.find("Table");
    var row = $("[id*=bankmodulgrid] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    $("[id*=bankmodulgrid] tr").not($("[id*=bankmodulgrid] tr:first-child")).remove();
    $.each(customers, function () {
        var customer = $(this);
        $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("harid").text());
        $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("compbankhartarix").text());
        $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("carikartad").text());
        $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("compbankharesaskod").text());
        $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("compbankharesas2kod").text());
        $("td", row).eq(5).html($(this).find("compbankharvalyuta").text());
        $("td", row).eq(6).html($(this).find("compbankharvalmebleg").text());
        $("[id*=bankmodulgrid]").append(row);
        row = $("[id*=bankmodulgrid] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    });
}



}
```

My html code

```
<div class="w3-row w3-section">
                            <div class="w3-rest">
                        <asp:Button id="bankmodulelaveet" runat="server" Text="Siyahıya əlavə et" Height="30px" Width="100%" Font-Size="Small" OnClientClick="bankmodulhargetir();return false;"   CssClass="w3-btn w3-white w3-border w3-border-gray w3-left w3-hover-blue"></asp:Button>

                                </div>
                                    </div> <br />

                       <div class="w3-responsive">






                        <asp:GridView ID="bankmodulgrid" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" CssClass="w3-table-all w3-left w3-responsive"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="12px" DataKeyNames="harid" RowStyle-ForeColor="Black" RowStyle-Font-Bold="true"
         OnRowDeleting="bankmodulgrid_RowDeleting"
         OnRowDataBound="bankmodulgrid_RowDataBound" >
        <Columns>


            <asp:BoundField DataField="harid" HeaderText="№" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="harid"   />



            <asp:BoundField DataField="compbankhartarix" HeaderText="Tarix" ControlStyle-CssClass="compbankhartarix" >
                <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
                <ItemStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="12px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="carikartad" HeaderText="Müştəri" ControlStyle-CssClass="carikartad" >
                <HeaderStyle Width="25%" />
                <ItemStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="12px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="compbankharesaskod" HeaderText="Əsas-1" ControlStyle-CssClass="compbankharesaskod"  >
                <HeaderStyle Width="20%" />
                <ItemStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="12px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="compbankharesas2kod" HeaderText="Əsas-2" ControlStyle-CssClass="compbankharesas2kod" >
                <HeaderStyle Width="20%" />
                <ItemStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="12px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>



            <asp:BoundField DataField="compbankharvalyuta" HeaderText="Valyuta" ControlStyle-CssClass="compbankharvalyuta"  >
                <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                <ItemStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="12px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="compbankharvalmebleg" HeaderText="Məbləğ" ControlStyle-CssClass="compbankharvalmebleg" >
                <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                <ItemStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="12px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Əməliyyatlar"  >
               <ItemStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="10px"/>

                 <ItemTemplate >

              <asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text='Delete'  ImageUrl="Images/Symbol-Delete.png" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

                           </div>
```

My c#:

[WebMethod]
    public static string bankmodulhargetirstatic(bankmodulvalues bankmodulvalues)
    {
        modulkod = "FIN102";
        nomreyoxla = bankmodulvalues.bankmodulnom;

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["sistemsenediyadd"] != null)

    {
        sistemsenedid = HttpContext.Current.Session["sistemsenediyadd"].ToString();
    }



    string query = "select har.HereketID as harid, ck.carikartad,format(har.compbankhartarix,'dd-MM-yyyy') as compbankhartarix,har.compbankharvalyuta,har.compbankharvalmebleg,har.compbankharesaskod,har.compbankharesas2kod  " +
        " from compbankhar har with (Nolock) " +
        "  left outer join carikart ck with (nolock) on ck.carikartkod = har.compbankharmusterikod " +
        "  where har.compbankharkod = '" + nomreyoxla + "' and har.compbankharsistemid = '" + sistemsenedid + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
}
private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JAMPROCONNECT"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work

[image: Screen]

[image: Screen]

Comment: Please stick to the question, and remove salutations and "formatting" like your dots at the beginning.

Comment: Are you trying to return rows a GridView via ajax? Sounds a bit crazy. Why not just return a regular table, or just return the data and build the table client-side with a templating engine? None of the useful features of a gridview (other than perhaps databinding) will work when doing it like this. Certainly nothing client-side like editing, postbacks, will work properly on the fetched rows. A standard HTML table would be simpler to use. Anyway, the question cannot be answered without seeing the code of the C# bankmodulhargetirstatic method, because that's where the databinding etc happens.

Comment: ADyson i'm add my c# code.

Comment: ok thanks. What exactly do you mean "ajax returns header row of gridview"? From the C# method which is called by ajax, you're simply outputting the XML from a Dataset, nothing to do with the gridview directly. XML doesn't really have any concept of a "header" row, and certainly the GetXML method should only return data. What does the XML actually look like when you get it into the Javascript?

Comment: @ADyson i add Screen from app.

Comment: Which part of that do you consider to be the problem? I don't know your language and cannot understand what I am looking at. Also, that doesn't answer my question - look in your browser's developer tools, find your ajax request in the Network section and look at the response. Does the XML look the way you expect? Does it contain "header" information in the way you're describing?

Comment: @ADyson my request in the network expect 
"<NewDataSet>
↵  <Table>
↵    <harid>1494</harid>
↵    <carikartad>. BŞİH .</carikartad>
↵    <compbankhartarix>15-01-2018</compbankhartarix>
↵    <compbankharvalyuta>AZN</compbankharvalyuta>
↵    <compbankharvalmebleg>5.00</compbankharvalmebleg>
↵    <compbankharesaskod>HM-PAMM1HUQ101-000072</compbankharesaskod>
↵  </Table>
↵</NewDataSet>"   i cant get data from this. in gridview compbankharesaskod column shuld be cunstracted HM-PAMM1HUQ101-000072.

Comment: @ADyson Could I explain the problem?

Comment: See this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s0xt9nqf/2/ your Javascript code works fine, based on that XML data (obviously I had to use a standard HTML table, but that's what a GridView is rendered as anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem). Hard to see what the issue is, with the information I have available.

Comment: Oh wait, I got it. `dataType: "json"`. Your response is XML. Why would you tell jQuery to expect JSON? Makes no sense. Try with `dataType:"xml"` and also change to `function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xml = $(response);`

Comment: @ADyson thanks for answer, i'm change everything as you say. but now i get undefined.

Comment: which thing precisely is undefined? http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html gives a simple example of the principle I was showing you. Plenty of other examples online as well. You perhaps need to do a bit more detailed debugging.  If it doesn't work you could also try setting data type as text and then using .parseXML as previous

Comment: @ADyson, i change   dataType: "xml",  and  function OnSuccess(response) {
       // var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d); - turn of this
        alert("ok1");
        var xml = $(xml);   now i can get alert result, i get undefined msg.

Comment: If you look closely at my code, I did `var xml = $(response);` not `var xml = $(xml);` You need to use a variable which actually exists beforehand. Try to pay attention to the specifics, and/or use copy and paste!

Comment: ups. sorry, my inattention. i changed var xml = $(response); but result is the same. i got undefined.

Comment: again, what specifically is undefined? You said "i can get alert result, i get undefined", but you have no variable called "result". What are you alerting, exactly? Have you got any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: i’am working with visual studio, and there i cant know on wich jquery row i get undefined. because i put alert(“ok”) after every row to get in wich row i get this issue. now i put errors from my browsesr’s console.

Comment: @ADyson, i'am checked, i havent got any errors in my browser's console. but i cant get rows in may gridview, when i write in datatype: json and xml = $(response); then i get datarows as header of gridview as in screenshoot, but now i cant get any data rows. when javacode is doing function (OnSuccess) i got undefined error message in my browser.

Comment: you still didn't tell me _what_ is undefined. Is it `response`? or `xml`? Which thing?

Comment: response is undefined.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dkNZ.png this is i get.

Comment: Did you try my second suggestion, setting datatype to text and re-introducing the parseXML? Perhaps jQuery has an issue with automatically parsing the XML in the response.

Comment: @ADyson, yes i try second suggestion, i dont get any errors, but everytime gridview is empty, code cant insert any data into gridview.

Comment: This is frustrating, because as per that example I gave in the link earlier, the code should work. Perhaps your XML is corrupted somehow coming from the server. You'll have to break down the code into pieces to verify each part. First try temporarily replacing the ajax response with a static XML string and ensure the rest of your code works as expected. It looks like it should. Then try seeing if there is anything odd about your server response - strange extra characters or something, which makes it not usable.

Comment: @ADyson, ok, thanks a lot. i verify my code, and write about results.

Comment: I also recommend you replace your GridView with a simple HTML table - since you are fetching the data from the server anyway and inserting normal `<tr>`s into it, you get none of the benefits a gridview can give. It'll simplify your markup and make it much easier to verify that your jQuery is working on the markup you expect. A Gridview definition just gets turned into a HTML table anyway by .NET when it creates the page, but if you write your own HTML you can have total control over what is created, and the markup is simpler and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I find problem, it was this code.

```
public void BindHeaderRowInGridview()
    {
        DataTable dtDummy = new DataTable();
        DataColumn column;
        foreach (DataControlField field in bankmodulgrid.Columns)
        {
            column = new DataColumn();
            if (field is BoundField)
            {
                BoundField bfield = field as BoundField;
                column.ColumnName = (field as BoundField).DataField;
                dtDummy.Columns.Add(column);
            }

        }

        dtDummy.Rows.Add();
        bankmodulgrid.DataSource = dtDummy;
        bankmodulgrid.DataBind();

    }

 protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindHeaderRowInGridview();
        }

    }
```

BindHeaderRowInGridview() dont work in pageload with !ispostback in my app. i put BindHeaderRowInGridview() function into another void. are you know because of what BindHeaderRowInGridview() may not work in pageload?